# Scrapy can't check duplicate item

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm new to python and I try to write a crawler by scrapy. I've followed the doc scrapy to remove duplicate crawled item but it didn't work. selft.ids_seen return []. Here my pipeline:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Products, db_connect, create_products_table
import logging

class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()
        logging.warning(self.ids_seen)
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['id'])
            logging.warning(item['id'])
            return item  

class TikiPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        engine = db_connect()
        create_products_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        session = self.Session()
        product = Products(**item)
        try:
            session.add(product)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()
        return item
```

My setting.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'tiki.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline': 100,
   'tiki.pipelines.TikiPipeline': 300,
}
```

Can anyone explain me what set() method will return? Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint and debug the `else` part in duplicate check?

Comment: Yes. I did. self.ids_seen is null once a request crawl